# Can I use a yoshimura exhaust in any bike?

Tags: motorcycle, exhaust

I have an old Triumph motorcycle 955i that im customising.
I want to change the exhaust and use a second hand [yoshimura cheap one](http://www.gumtree.com.au/s-ad/bulli/motorcycle-scooter-parts/suzuki-gsxr-600-750-yoshimura-exhaust/1192549159?utm_campaign=socialbuttons&utm_content=app_ios&utm_medium=social&utm_source=ios_social)

Is that possible? Or the exhaust needs to handle different pressure or other variable?

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is it a 2 stroke engine?  Is the exhaust designed for a 2 stroke engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that second hand exhaust was designed for an engine of similar capacity and type, but not smaller, then it should be fine.

If you don't have a smooth transition from one pipe diameter to the other, then you can cause weird problems due to pressure characteristics created by the abrupt change in diameter.

The other issue is the fixing points, but that is something to deal with when you look at how it fits.

Comment: One issue than can occur with changing exhaust is fuel mixture. A freer flowing exhaust  can cause a lean mixture. This may require rejetting if it has a carb, or retuning if it has fuel injection. You will notice either backfiring or the engine will bog down if this becomes an issue.

Comment: @mikes later fuel injection with maf, map & O2 sensors etc should cope with that though...